# Ajax GET request adding extra parameter in the ROUTE with Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to make a AJAX GET request on click with jQuery in Laravel. The route is defined on this

`Route::get('/somefunc/{alias1}/{alias2}', 'uses'=>'MyController@myfunction']);`

The route link I'm trying to access is defined here:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var parameterValues = $(this).attr('value');

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'somefunc/somealiashere/'+alias2value,
        data: parameterValues,
        dataType:"json"

    })
```

But when I try to send the request on the link it gives me extra parameter in the route:

`items/somefunc/somealiashere/1`

because of the previous resource define in the web.php.

How to skip that 'items' parameter in the route.

Thank you.

Comment: how about not using a relative path then ... i guess you are currently on 'youriste.com/items'

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are sending GET request. Change it to POST and update route. If you need to send GET request you don't need to add X-CSRF-TOKEN header.